# OpenTSDB - Get the last data point for a metric timeseries before a given timestamp

Tags: opentsdb

**Use case**

I want to find the last data point for a metric timeseries just before or on a given timestamp from OpenTSDB.

**So far** I tried

> api/query/last HTTP API

It did provide the last data point for a metric after changing opentsdb config and adding

```
tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_uid = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_ts = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_incrementing = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_tracking = true
```

I there any way to query it with a timestamp, or any other api/way to get the desired result.

Comment: You can try `api/query` with the largest downsampling window (`0all`) and apply `last` aggregation function.

Comment: Thanks @srkavin this seems to the trick!. I do have one follow up question  is there any way to filter on the value which we get after applying  the last aggregation.

Comment: as far as I know, filters can be applied only on tag values. You may have to do this final metric value based filtering in the app.

Comment: @srkavin the `0all-last` combo that you mentioned give the correct value, but the timestamp is the start time of the query. Is there a way to get the actual timestamp of the last data point instead?